# Find the general matrix commuting with a Jordan canonical Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find the most general matrix X commuting with 
$ J= D_{g} [J_{2}(2), J_{1}(2), J_{2}(3), J_{1}(3)] $

I also need to find the dimension of $ C(J) $ the centralizer of $ J $.

I have found the general matrix X=
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc|c|cc|c} 
a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
b & a & c & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
d & 0 & e & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & f & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & g & f & h \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & i & 0 & j\\
\end{array}\right) 
$$

I am not sure how to find the dimension of C(J).

If I understand what my textbook says:
$d= 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 10 $

Comment: You've got it-a basis for the centralizer is the ten different versions of your general commuting matrix in which all but one variable is set to 0 and the other is set to 1.